# how to deploy a voila app with custom favicon?

Tags: python, heroku, voila

To deploy my [voila application](https://sepal-map-app.herokuapp.com/) I'm using the recipe from the template provided in the [voila repository](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-heroku).

The application work as expected but I don't manage to set-up a custom favicon. is it even possible ?

Comment: Did you see [this suggestion about whitelisting that static file](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/664#issuecomment-697977818)?

Comment: I did and I tried, I didn't see any change from my side. Even if the file is whitelisted I don't see how to add it to the generated html.

Comment: update on my latest comment, it seems it was just about my browser cache. The favicon is now there. if you publish it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sure you [whitelist that static file](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/664#issuecomment-697977818).